# Adding checkboxes to an html table to then be able to remove data from sql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I am very fresh to php/sql.. Enjoying what I have learned so far, I am stumped on this right now..

Here is my current code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM beings"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Question</th><th>Time Submitted</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['location'] . "</td><td>" . $row["question"] . "</td><td>" . $row["submitted"] ."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
```

What I would like to do, is have a column of checkboxes either on the right or left side of the table, and a button at the bottom so I can check a box and then have it remove the data from the database.

How do I have it add a checkbox(which would be a new `<td>` entry) for every entry it finds in the while loop?
Any help on this is very appreciated! 
Thanks all!

Comment: You need to stop using `mysql_` functions as they have been deprecated. Use `mysqli_/PDO` instead. Also, you might want to follow a simple tutorial like this: http://openegg.ca/checkbox-with-php-and-mysql/ Try the code and then post a question here with specific things that are not working.

Comment: Google this; there are plenty of examples on the Web which will more than likely lead you back here on Stack with Q&A's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution without jQuery**

If you don't want to use jQuery, then add "action" to the form as the same php page which has the form and the checkboxes.

```
<form method="POST"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM beings"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['location'] . "</td><td>" . $row["question"] . "</td><td>" . $row["submitted"] ."</td><td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['name']."'  name='".$row['name']."'> </td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close();

?>
<input type="submit" id="#btn" value="Sumbit" />
</form>
```

And when this form is submitted the form data will be posted to this php file itself,so you need to add the Form processing and row deletion code on top of this page(above html form).

```
<?php 
//make connection to the database
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
if(isset($_POST)){
    //if say there were 2 checkboxes checked with entries as 'a'and 'b'before submiting the form then $_POST['a']='a' and $_POST['b']='b'
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    //inside this loop we will make a query which will delete the name one by one
    //in the first iteration the $query will become
    //   DELETE from beings WHERE name = 'a'
        $query= "DELETE from beings WHERE name = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$key);
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        // 'mysqli_real_escape_string' function is used to prevent SQL injection.That is a separate and very important topic.This function just say sanitize the data coming from user(which may or may not be tampered)
    }
}
?>
```

Try to print the values of $key $value and $query inside the for loop to understand better.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!
I have learned immensely from this project! Really getting it!

Thank you again! :) 
Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

**Q1: How do I have it add a checkbox?**
Ans : `echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['location'] . "</td><td>" . $row["question"] . "</td><td>" . $row["submitted"] ."</td><td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['name']."'  name='".$row['name']."'> </td></tr>";`

What this does is, it will add a check box to the right of the table and each checkbox having a different name (I am assuming 'name' column of your table is having unique values).

**Q2: Select and delete those entries**
Ans : For this you can add this script

```
<script> 

$("#delete_form").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"delete_names.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:$("#delete_form").serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            $('#response').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

and the HTML page will be like

```
    <form method="POST" id="delete_form">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM beings"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['location'] . "</td><td>" . $row["question"] . "</td><td>" . $row["submitted"] ."</td><td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['name']."'  name='".$row['name']."'> </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close();

    ?>
    <input type="submit" id="#btn" value="Sumbit" />
    </form>
    <div id="response" > </div>
```

and the delete_name.php will be like

```
<?php 
    //make connection to the database
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        $query= "DELETE from beings WHERE name = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$key);
        $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
?>
```

PS:You need to stop using mysql_ functions as they have been deprecated. Use mysqli_/PDO instead.I have have used them so that you could understand the procedure of solving this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried what you suggested, and the rows do not delete. Also, the javascript sort of throws me off right now. Is this possible with just php?

Comment: I can comprehend how when the box is checked it gets a value. Then the values go into an array. Then the array can be processed with "DELETE FROM beings WHERE name is".
I am very fresh at all of this. Can you break down what is all happening here? It will help me to grasp the flow of everything better. Thank you again for your assistance.